# Android speech recognition over Bluetooth headset sometimes omits beep to prompt user to speak

Tags: android, bluetooth, speech-recognition, headset

My app already does speech recognition.  A user told me it didn't work with a Bluetooth headset.  I was able to, mostly, get speech recognition working over the Bluetooth headset (thanks to another Stack Overflow contributor, no thanks to the official Android documentation).

There is one annoying problem, however: when switching to use the Bluetooth headset, it can obliterate audio output briefly during the switchover.  In particular, it can sometimes omit the beep that ordinarily prompts the user for speech recognition.

My current workaround is to put in a one-second delay, after the Bluetooth headset has been connected to the SCO audio channel, before doing speech recognition.

My question: is there a more reliable method of avoiding this conflict?

```
static AudioManager sAudioManager;
static BluetoothHeadset sBluetoothHeadset;
static BluetoothDevice sBluetoothDevice;

static public void initBluetooth(Context pContext)
{
    sAudioManager = (AudioManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Register to get notifications about Bluetooth profiles

    sBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(
        pContext, new BluetoothProfileListener(), BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

    // Register to receive notification when the headset is dis/connected

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
    pContext.registerReceiver(
        new BluetoothHeadsetBroadcastReceiver(), intentFilter);
}

public static void startSpeechRecognition()
{
    sAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    sAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    sAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);

    sBluetoothHeadset.startVoiceRecognition(sBluetoothDevice);
}

public static void stopSpeechRecognition()
{
    sBluetoothHeadset.stopVoiceRecognition(sBluetoothDevice);

    sAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
    sAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
    sAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
}

static public void doSpeechRecognition(Context pContext)
{
    SpeechRecognizer sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(pContext);
    Intent intent =
        new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(
        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    sr.startListening(intent);
}

static public class BluetoothHeadsetBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent pIntent)
    {
        int state = pIntent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
        if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED)
        {
            // CURRENT WORKAROUND
            // Delay speech recognition to avoid obliterating beep prompt

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            };

            doSpeechRecognition(pContext);
        }
    }
}

static public class BluetoothProfileListener implements BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int pProfile, BluetoothProfile pProxy)
    {
        sBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) pProxy;

        List<BluetoothDevice> devices = pProxy.getConnectedDevices();
        int numDevices = devices.size();

        if (numDevices > 0)
        {
            BluetoothDevice device = devices.get(0);
            sBluetoothDevice = device;
        }
    }
}
```